# difficulties with Django ''follow'' other user ( RedirectView )

Tags: python, django, view

I have a problem with a class in my Views.py

```
class FollowToggle(RedirectView):
def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
    username = self.kwargs.get("username")
    userprofile = self.kwargs.get("userprofile")
    user = self.request.user
    obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if user in obj.follow.all():
            obj.follow.remove(user)
        else: 
            obj.follow.add(user)
    url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
    return url_
```

I want to give an User the option to follow each other. I have this call which I want to use later in an API. (everything is set up and running) but right now all It does is following itself. so if a user is doing http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/testuser/follow it redirects to the last page and updated the data in the model, but the followed user is the user himself. 
I figured that the Problem is obj.follow.remove(user) here should 'user' be 'username' but this throws me an error (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'testuser').

If anybody knows how to solve this please let me know.

Models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    follow = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,default=1, related_name='follow')

    def get_follow_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:follow-toggle", kwargs={"user": self.user})

    def get_api_follow_url(self):
        return reverse ("profiles:follow-api-toggle", kwargs={"user": self.user})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles", kwargs={"username": self.user})
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing because the view has two kwargs `username` and `userprofile`, but the url `/profiles/testuser/follow` appears to have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the username or profile string from the url, and use that to fetch the user object. You can then use this with `obj.follow.add()` or ``obj.follow.remove()`

```
other_user_username = self.kwargs.get("username")
other_user = get_object_or_404(User, username=other_user_username)
...
obj.follow.add(other_user)
```

Comment: Probably more `obj.follow.add(other_user)` on your last line

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot. im sitting on this for 5 hours. now im having just some small problems with the api but I will figure it out :)